# colorbar　の上限、下限を定めたい

Tags: julia

pythonのようなsen.heatmapを使う際、横軸に出力されるｚの値を制限するときは

```
vmin=0.0,vmax=...
```

のように指定することでできますが、これに相当するJuliaの指定はあるのでしょうか？

だいぶ調べたのですが、climなどを使っても制御はできなかったのですが、、、

どなたか知っている方がを折りましたら、ご教授ください。

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(data,...,cbar_lims=(0,0.18))
```

cbar_lims以外にもclimなどもあります

でできました